# Dialog or pop up showing an information from a list

Tags: python, kivymd

Okay so I created a list of items and each list has a specific information that I want to always show up when the list is clicked. So my question is what is the right code to put in the list that when clicked or on release, shows the information like a dialog box then okay button to close the dialog

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can’t get the code here because it’s not working but what I’m trying to say is, I have an item on a list, let’s say there are three items on my list. A ball a pen and a bicycle, now I want to explain what a ball is, so when I click on the ball, I want something like a dialog box to come on the screen with the explanation of that ball and if you click on the rest items on the list the same thing happens. That’s my question

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: OneLineIconListItem:
          text: ‘item1’
           icon: ‘oil’
           On_release : show_dialog(market)

OneLineIconListItem:
          text: ‘item2’
           icon: ‘python-language’
           On_release : show_dialog(house)